# Strict WQOs and Strict WPOs

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

The [Wikipedia article on WQOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering) does not mention a *strict* version. I came across a particular relation, which I could only describe as a strict WQO, but I am wondering if my reasoning is correct and if the notion of a "strict WQO" even makes sense (I think it does).

Consider the set $X \times \mathbb{N}$ where $X = \{1,\ldots,k\}$ for some integer $k$ and $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers. We define the relation $\prec$ as:
$$ (x_1,n_1) \prec (x_2,n_2) \quad \text{iff} \quad (x_1 \leq x_2) \wedge (n_1 < n_2) $$

*Strict Quasi Order*: Clearly $\prec$ is irreflexive and transitive, and therefore a strict quasi order.

*No Infinite Antichains*: It's also easy to observe that there are no infinite antichains. Due to the Pigeonhole principle, any sequence $(x_1,n_1), (x_2,n_2), \ldots$ of length $\geq k$ must have at least one pair $\langle (x_i,n_i),(x_j,n_j)\rangle$ such that $x_i = x_j$. Then, since either $n_i < n_j$ or $n_j < n_i$ must hold, we have at least one pair in the sequence on which $\prec$ holds.

*Well-Foundedness*: Finally, we show that there are no infinite descending chains. For any element $(i,j)$, there are only $|\{1,\ldots,i\} \times \{1,\ldots,(j-1)\}| = i(j-1)$ elements that can precede $(i,j)$.

Is this reasoning correct? Then is $\prec$ a strict WQO on $X \times \mathbb{N}$?

**Related questions:**
Since antisymmetry is implied by irreflexivity and transitivity, is any strict quasi order also a strict partial order? And so is any strict WQO also a strict WPO?

Thanks.

Comment: First, a constant sequence is a counterexample to your "easy to observe" claim. I guess byat by "any infinite sequence" you meant "any infinite sequence of distinct terms".

Comment: Second, the definition of wqo says that, in any infinite sequence $x_i$, there exist $i\lt j$ such that $x_i\le x_j$. Your notion is quite different because you omitted the "$I\lt j$" condition.

Comment: I think the property you are trying to express is that every invinite set of distinct elements contains a comparable pair, or in other words, that there is no infinite antichain (no infinite set of pairwise incomparable elements). Well-wuasi-ordering is the conjunction of two conditions: "there is no infinite antichain" and "there is no decreasing infinite sequence".

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I have also added a proof for the "there is no decreasing infinite sequence" condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\leq$ is any relation, let $<$ be the strict version when $x<y$ if and only if ($x\leq y$ and $x\neq y$). There's really not much more to defining a strict relation. Note that we can alternatively start with $<$ and define $x\leq y$ as ($x<y$ or $x=y$).

So, to check that your $\prec$ relation is a strict WQO, we define $\preceq$ as $x\preceq y$ if and only if ($x\prec y$ or $x=y$).

- $\preceq$ is reflexive by definition, since $x=x$ implies $x\preceq x$
- $\preceq$ is transitive: this follows easily from the transitivity of $\leq$ and $<$ on $X$ and $\mathbb N$ respectively.
- Well-founded: let $\langle (x_i,n_i)\mid i\in\mathbb N\rangle$ be an infinite sequence. By the infinite pigeonhole principle and $X$ being finite, there is an $x\in X$ such that $I=\{i\in \mathbb N\mid x_i=x\}$ is infinite. Let $\langle(x,n_i)\mid i\in I\rangle$ be the subsequence consisting of those elements, then $(x,n_i)\preceq(x,n_j)$ iff $n_i\leq n_j$. Since $\mathbb N$ is well-ordered, there must be $i,j\in I$ such that $i<j$ and $n_i\leq n_j$, hence there exist $i<j$ such that $(x_i,n_i)\preceq(x_j,n_j)$.

Now, the relation $\preceq$ is antisymmetric as well: if $(x,n)\neq(y,m)$ and $(x,n)\preceq(y,m)$, then $n<m$, thus $m\not <n$, thus $(y,m)\not\preceq(x,n)$. Therefore $\preceq$ is in fact a WPO.

---

It is true that antisymmetry is implied by irreflexivity and transitivity. However, it is not true that a strict WQO is transitive.

As a very simple example, take $\{a,b\}$ with the universal relation ${\trianglelefteq}=\{(a,b),(b,a),(a,a),(b,b)\}$. It is easy to see this is a WQO and not a WPO. However, the strict relation $\triangleleft=\{(a,b),(b,a)\}$  is no longer transitive.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer perfectly addresses my questions.